# get upcoming time that may be of the next date

Tags: php

I have following code that always returns time of the same date,

```
$time = time();
if ($time < strtotime("09:00:00") || $time > strtotime("17:00:00")) {
   $nextTime = strtotime("09:00:00");
   return $nextTime;
}
```

I want to return upcoming time that may be of the next date.

Expected result: If time is before 9AM it should return 9AM time of the same day, or if time is after 5PM it should return 9AM time of next day.

Comment: also mention $time value

Comment: question edited

Comment: And what is the condition when next date should be returned?

Comment: @Syed, what is the exact expected result?

Comment: If time is before 9AM it should return 9AM time of the same day, or if time is after 5PM it should return 9AM time of next day.

Comment: And what if the time is between 9AM and 5PM?

Comment: If the time is between 9AM and 5PM I will do my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the DateTime object to compare the date and time:

```
function dateCompare($dateToCompare)
{
    $nineAM = clone $dateToCompare;
    $nineAM->setTime(9, 0, 0);
    $fivePM = clone $dateToCompare;
    $fivePM->setTime(17, 0, 0);

    if ($dateToCompare < $nineAM) {
        return $nineAM;
    }

    if ($dateToCompare > $fivePM) {
        $nineAM->modify('+1 day');
        return $nineAM;
    }

    return $dateToCompare;
}

var_dump(dateCompare(new DateTime()));
```